# Unable to find advertisements with BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher

Tags: c#, windows, .net-core, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to make an app that advertises a payload and another than scans for and picks this up using bluetooth low energy. However when i use a windows(11) device to advertise and another windows(10) device to scan for this, the BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher does not show those particular advertisements.

I checked with the nRF connect android app, and it does show the device and data I'm advertising, so the advertising does work fine. And the BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher does show some other devices.

For reference here's the basic code i use for advertising and scanning. Both are Winui3 desktop apps.

Advertising app:

```
    private BluetoothLEAdvertisementPublisher pub = new();

    private void StartAdvertising() {
            pub.Advertisement.ManufacturerData.Add(CreateData("hello"));
            pub.Start();
        }

    private BluetoothLEManufacturerData CreateData(string data) {
            var datawriter = new DataWriter();
            datawriter.WriteInt32(data.Length);
            datawriter.WriteString(data);
            return new BluetoothLEManufacturerData(0x7005, datawriter.DetachBuffer());
        }
```

Scanning app:

```
      private BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher = new();

      public void StartDeviceWatcher() {
            watcher.ScanningMode = BluetoothLEScanningMode.Active;
            watcher.Received += AdvertisementReceiver;
            watcher.Start();
        }

      private async void AdvertisementReceiver(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher sender,
       BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs e) {
            using BluetoothLEDevice bleDevice =
                await BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(e.BluetoothAddress);
            if (bleDevice != null) {
                Log.D(TAG,
                    $"BleDeviceScanner : {e.Advertisement.LocalName} Id- {bleDevice.DeviceId.ToUpper()} Rx- {e.RawSignalStrengthInDBm}");
         
            }
        }
```

Why does the BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher not show those particular advertisements? Am i missing something in my code?